# Separar la Data Cada cierta cantidad de Registros y agregar una cabecera

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo 2 tablas en SQL: 
dbo.header: contiene la información de cabecera.
dbo.Temp1: contiene el detalle de los registros.

Digamos que dbo.Temp1 tiene 5,000 registros.

Se necesita por cada 1000 registros agregar la cabecera(dbo.header).

Ejemplo:

----LINEA DE CABECERA----
Registros 1..............................
Registros 2..............................
.
.
.
Registro 1000 ...........................
-----LINEA DE CABECERA----
Registros 1,001..............................
Registros 1,002..............................
.
.
.
Registro 2000 ...........................
-----LINEA DE CABECERA------
.
.
.
Y así sucesivamente.

Alguien podría apoyarme indicando o sugiriendo cual sería la mejor forma de realizar esto.

Gracias

Saludos,

Comment: Dinos en qué contexto necesitas mostrar la información porque quizá esto es mejor resolverlo por programación, sería cuestión de leer los datos en un bucle y poner los encabezados cada `N` filas.

Comment: Hola, Seria utilizando script de SQL Server

Comment: Entonces podrías escribir una función o procedimientos que obtenga por un lado los encabezados y por otro lado vas obteniendo los datos en grupo de `N` filas y vas mostrando las cabeceras y esos datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[header](
[col1] [varchar](20) NULL,
[col2] [varchar](20) NULL,
[col3] [varchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temp1](
[id] [int] NULL,
[col1] [varchar](100) NULL,
[col2] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[header] ([col1], [col2], [col3]) 
VALUES 
(N'identificador', N'nombre', N'apellido')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Temp1] ([id], [col1], [col2]) 
VALUES 
(1, N'JUAN',    N'A1' ),
(2, N'CARLOS',  N'A2' ),
(3, N'MARIA',   N'A3' ),
(4, N'BEA',     N'A4' ),
(5, N'ISA',     N'A5' ),
(6, N'ANA',     N'A6' ),
(7, N'PEDRO',   N'A7' ),
(8, N'SOLE',    N'A8' ),
(9, N'RAUL',    N'A9' ),
(10, N'ABEL',   N'A10'),
(11, N'EVA',    N'A11'),
(12, N'ELISA',  N'A12'),
(13, N'SEVE',   N'A13'),
(14, N'RODRI',  N'A14'),
(15, N'LUIS',   N'A15'),
(16, N'MIGUEL', N'A16'),
(17, N'ALEA',   N'A17');
```

Con el escenario que planteas. Un ejemplo puede ser poniendo el encabezado cada 3 registros.

```
declare @contador int = (select COUNT(*) from dbo.Temp1);
declare @tampag int = 3;

;with r as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as ROW
        from  sys.objects a
        cross join sys.objects b
        cross join sys.objects c
),
 r2 as (
  select   r.row, case when r.row % @tampag = 0 then row 
                       when r.row = 1 then row 
                       else null
                  end as cabecera
        from r 
    where r.row <= @contador
  ), r3 as (
  select case when ROW > 1 then ROW+1 
                else ROW end as row 
  from r2
    where cabecera is not null
  )
  , r4 as (
  select   0 as orden
         , r3.row
         , h.col1
         , h.col2
         , h.col3 
  from  r3
  cross join dbo.header h
  )
  , filas as (
    select 1 as orden
          ,t.id
          , CAST ( t.id as varchar(10)) as col1
          , t.col1 as col2
          , t.col2 as col3
     from dbo.Temp1 t
    union all 
    select r4.orden
         , r4.[row]
         , r4.col1
         , r4.col2
         , r4.col3 
    from r4
  )
    select F.col1
         , F.col2
         , F.col3 
         from filas F
  order by F.id, F.orden
```

Salida:

[image: Resultados]

Comment: Lo siento pero he tenido el gusto de pegarme con Teradata